# Nginx giving 403 code for django static files

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my django project. In my django settings, static file settings are like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/root/www/static'
```

so my static files are in /root/www/static directory, i can see them in the server. My nginx server block is like this:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   location /static/ {
   root /root/www;
   }

   location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

when i browse my application with browser, i'm getting

> 403 - Forbidden

error for static files.

Comment: Why have you put them under "/root"? That's for files accessible by the root user only.

Comment: @DanielRoseman for no particular reason. I was just trying. Moved them from root and changed the settings. It's fine now. Post this as answer so i can accept ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't put the static files under `/root`: that's for files accessible via the root user only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with user permissions. You need to change the path that is accessible by the user for which the app is deployed.

The location should look something like this:

```
location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/srv/webapps/[app_name]/static;
    }
```

Try [this](http://ryangallen.com/wall/7/deploying-django-aws-ec2-instance/) tutorial for more help.